# Не работает установленный на ubuntu php-mongo

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu

Здравствуйте! Установил на ubuntu php-mongo как написано здесь:

```
sudo apt-get install php-pear
sudo pecl install mongo
sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=mongo.so' > /etc/php5/conf.d/mongo.ini"
sudo service apache2 restart
php -i | grep -i mongo
```

Установить-то я установил. Но при попытке в php-файле вызвать `$trymongo = new Mongo('mongodb://localhost:27017');`
пишет, что класс Mongo не обнаружен. nginx перезапущен,php5-fpm тоже перезапущен. В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Может, свё-таки `new MongoClient(...)`, а не `new Mongo(...)`?

http://php.net/manual/ru/mongo.tutorial.connecting.php

Comment: Да нет, не MongoClient(...) - я его тоже попробовал. Тем более в YiiMongoDbSuite используется именно эта конструкция. Я прописал в php.ini extension=mongo.so, но phpInfo() не отображает этого. Что я сделал не так?

Comment: А параметр `extension_dir` в php.ini куда указывает? Должен в папку, где лежит mongo.so.

Comment: Параметр extension_dir я изменил на /usr/lib/php5/20121212/ , где лежит mongo.so. Ничего не заработало (я перезапустил всё что можно, phpInfo() отразил мои изменения). Но, зато, в других источниках я видел, что нужно куда-то в php.ini поместить extension=mongo.so. А куда добавлять это надо?

Comment: Ну, вы строчкой

    sudo sh -c "echo 'extension=mongo.so' > /etc/php5/conf.d/mongo.ini"

должны были это сделать. Проверьте, в тот ли php.ini эта строка записалась.

Comment: Всё. У меня получилось! Да я просто в /etc/php5/fpm/conf.d сделал ссылку (ln -s) на файл /etc/php5/conf.d/mongo.ini

Answer (score 1):

Вывод

```
php -i | grep -i mongo
```

В студию. Должно быть что то в духе

```
/etc/php5/cli/conf.d/mongo.ini,
mongo
MongoDB Support => enabled
mongo.allow_persistent => 1 => 1
mongo.auto_reconnect => 1 => 1
mongo.chunk_size => 262144 => 262144
mongo.cmd => $ => $
mongo.default_host => localhost => localhost
mongo.default_port => 27017 => 27017
mongo.long_as_object => 0 => 0
mongo.native_long => 0 => 0
mongo.utf8 => 1 => 1</pre>
```

Вообще в более или менее современных версиях ubuntu есть пакет php-mongo (php5-mongo) подключающий все за вас